# How to customize the jQuery DataTable Pagination Buttons and populate with several service calls

Tags: jquery, spring, datatables

I'm populating a jQuery datatable with a objects list which i'm fetching from a REST API. So i'm binding that to a modelAttribute and passing to the view. So the records are populated in the table. But the problem is the particular API only returns 10 records at once. So in my service method i'm only fetching 10 records. So once the datatable is loaded i need to do another service call and get the rest of the records once the next button is clicked in the table. How can I achieve this using the services and controllers?  Is there better way to do it maybe using AJAX?

The controller:

```
@Autowired
private PoyntApiClient poyntApiClient;

@RequestMapping(value = "/businessDetails/{businessId}/poynt", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewBusinessDetails(Model model, @PathVariable String businessId) throws IOException {

      PoyntBusinessDetails poyntBusinessDetails = new PoyntBusinessDetails();
      poyntBusinessDetails = poyntApiClient.getPoyntBusinessDetails( businessId);
      model.addAttribute("poyntBusinessDetails", poyntBusinessDetails);

    return POYNT_DETAILS_VIEW;
}
```

The view :

```
<table id="poyntSubcriptionsTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Business ID</th>
             <th>Plan Created Date</th>
             <th>Payment Status</th>
             <th>Subscription Phase</th>
             <th>Plan Name</th>
             <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <c:forEach items="${subscriptions}" var="item">
             <tr>
               <td>${item.businessId}</td>
               <td>${item.createdDate}</td>
               <td>${item.paymentStatus}</td>
               <td>${item.phase}</td>
               <td>${item.planName}</td>
               <td>${item.status}</td>                    
             </tr>
          </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
      </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#poyntSubcriptionsTable').DataTable({})
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the front-end According to the following code snippet.

```
$('#poyntSubcriptionsTable').DataTable({
            "serverSide": true,
            "processing": true,
            "searchDelay": 1000,
            "ajax": "your-controller/search?action=filterByState&status=" + filterStatus,
            "columns": [
                {"data": "id"},
                {"data": "title"}, 
            ],
            "pageLength": 25
        });
```

In the back-end side, you will receive following GET parameters and you can use them according to your requirement.

```
$_GET["start"] - Starting raw number. 
$_GET["length"] - Number of rows to fetch once 
$_GET["draw"] - Draw is a unique identifier for request and response (When ajax request send to do a searching it sends draw value as 1, when composing the search result response draw is set to 1 and re-send)
```

(Assume you have set length as 10 and in the first load, you get 1 to 10 records as the first page. Once you click page 2 then rows from 11 to 20 will be received.)

From the backend, your response JSON object should be as follows.

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":29629,
         "title":"fghfgh",
         "status":"PUBLISHED",
         "categories":"Accounting Software",
         "ext_ref_id":null,
         "created_time":"2018-08-06 11:45:18"
      },
      {
         "id":29628,
         "title":"hhh",
         "status":"PUBLISHED",
         "categories":"Bakers Supplies",
         "ext_ref_id":null,
         "created_time":"2018-08-06 09:26:24"
      }
   ],
   "recordsTotal":"29646",
   "recordsFiltered":"29646",
   "draw":1
}
```